# Concatenate values in a foreach into an input value attribube

Tags: php, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate values in a foreach into an input value attribube

**Part of the code**

```
foreach($orders as $order) {

$i++;

$data .= "<div class='order' row-id='".$order->rowID."'>
<div class='col-md-1 sub_chkbox'>
<input type='checkbox' class='sub_chk' name='orders[]'' data-id='".$order->orderID."' value='".$order->orderID."'>
</div>";
```

**Input value attribute**

```
value='".$order->orderID."'
```

**What I need to concatenate**

I need to concatenate `".$order->orderID."` with `".$order->rowID."` and a `"|"` separator.

**I have tried, but failed**

```
value='".$order->orderID." " | " ".$order->rowID."'
```

Comment: It failed you how? Did it not show any results or not what you thought? And/or, did it show errors? If so, what were they?

Comment: From what I can tell, you're only missing a few dots between both variables.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner 
Only first variable is shown not the second, if I test with dd($order->rowID); I get my value, so I guess yes I'm missing something

Comment: For readability's sake its probably better to generate that before hand: `$value = $order->orderID.'"|"'.$order->rowId;`

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I’d call it superfluous extra double quotes, rather than missing dots :-)

Comment: @04FS I had a feeling about something like that :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$value = $order->orderID . ' | ' . $order->rowID;

$data .= "
<div class='order' row-id='{$order->rowID}'>
  <div class='col-md-1 sub_chkbox'>
    <input type='checkbox' class='sub_chk' name='orders[]' data-id='{$order->orderID}' value='$value'>
  </div>
";
```